# call exchange contract's deposit method error

Tags: exchange, deposit

I encounter this problem when I call wanna deposit token in the exchange contract.(the private key imported correct).

Error 3090003: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set permission for this account:

```
cleos set account permission test active '{"threshold":1, "keys":[{"key":"YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY", "weight":1}], "accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"test","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p test
```